What does consistency mean in high-dimensional settings?
In some papers about $\mathcal{l}_1$-penalized regression,
$$
\hat{\beta}=\underset{\beta\in\mathbb{R}^{p}}{\operatorname{\arg\min}}\|Y-X\beta\|_2^2+\lambda\|\beta\|_1,
$$
the authors  say that they obtained some theoretical results for the estimators. One is the consistency of the estimator $\hat{\beta}$.
In high-dimensional settings, what does consistency really mean? Does consistency have different meanings in different places?

Consistency of an estimator $\hat\theta_n$ means that $P(\lVert \theta - \hat\theta_n \rVert > \varepsilon) \to 0$ as the sample size $n$ grows to infinity, for any small $\varepsilon>0$. I think in high-dimensional settings you'll simply use the appropriate multidimensional Euclidean norm, $\lVert x \rVert = \sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}$, but online people write $||$ or $\operatorname{plim}$ and don't discuss the norm involved.

What is a "high" dimension for you?

@whuber p$\gg$ n

And just how meaningful would that be for any kind of a mathematical definition of consistency?

I didn't express myself clearly. What I want to ask is what the term 'consistency' usually means in high-dimensional statistical papers, because it seems to have different definitions in different places, and it seems to be true.
